# (oh-my-)zsh behaviour: `$ command_name` at home directory results in `cd command_name` effect

Tags: linux, shell, path, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm currently using `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh`, and I've run into an annoying shell behaviour.

I must have done a subtle yet breaking change in the `$PATH` export while editing my `.zshrc`, because the following thing happens:

At the shell prompt while in `~/`, issuing, for example, the `flutter` command...

`$ flutter`

...results in:

`$ ~/flutter/`
(as if calling `$ flutter` had been interpreted as `$ cd flutter`)

However, issuing `$ flutter` **in any other directory, including `$ ~/flutter`** results in the *correct execution* of the `flutter` command. Same thing for `go` and others.

Line `2` on my `.zshrc` exports `$PATH` in the following fashion:

`export PATH=$HOME/bin:$HOME/.emacs.d:$HOME/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk:$HOME/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$HOME/.cargo/env:$HOME/.platformio/penv/bin:$HOME/flutter/bin:$PATH`

I've been comparing `.zshrc` versions with other backups, and I may be missing something, but no differences were found.

What seems off, in your opinion?

If you've encountered this annoyance before, how did you correct it?

Comment: That's a feature called `autocd`, not a bug

Comment: If I haven't explicitly activated it, how could it be in effect, and how can I deactivate it? It only happens with certain commands.

Comment: I don't know. Use a proper shell like bash instead

Comment: That's not very helpful.

Comment: well I can't help, google zsh autocd etc. maybe you'll find it, or file a bug

Comment: I appreciate the `autocd` heads-up, I'm currently looking into it. Next time, please refrain from bashing other people's tools. We all have different stacks for particular needs, and if some of us aren't using a particular tool (in this case `bash`), it's for a compelling reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

It'a feature called `AUTO_CD`.

> AUTO_CD (-J)
>
> If a command is issued that can’t be executed as a normal command, and the command is the name of a directory, perform the cd command to that directory.
>
> http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Changing-Directories

`AUTO_CD` is enabled by oh-my-zsh in file [`oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/76c7bd57c332b3d9231dc2c6167f3c5d3e56e110/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh#L40-L46).

```sh
...

setopt auto_cd
setopt multios
setopt prompt_subst

[[ -n "$WINDOW" ]] && SCREEN_NO="%B$WINDOW%b " || SCREEN_NO=""
...
```

#### Solution

Append the following command in `~/.zshrc` after `oh-my-zsh` is loaded to disable this feature.

```sh
unsetopt AUTO_CD
```

Comment: @dennismayr My pleasure if you can accept the answer.

Comment: Sure thing! I'll report this to the oh-my-zsh maintainers as well; `auto_cd` should be opt-in, not opt-out, and this "feature" wasn't in effect last week (I update after every prompt).